# ¿Regex para encontrar palabras que estén entre dos espacios?

Tags: javascript, regex

¿Cómo hacer un regex que salte true cuando aparezca "and" entre dos espacios? Por ejemplo:

```
"true and false" // returns true
```

Pero que no salte cuando "and" está unida, por ejemplo:

```
 "thousand" // returns false
```

Comment: Seguramente no necesites un regex para eso, pero en todo caso es directo: `" and "`, a menos que haya algo más que no has mencionado. Por ejemplo ¿quizás quieres que detecte también `and` al final de una línea? En ese caso en lugar de estar rodeada por espacios necesitas indicar que esté rodeada de "límites de palabra" (_word boundaries_), así: `"\\band\\b"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podías usar la función `includes` de Javascript. Busca la cadena que le pases como parámetro dentro de otra cadena o de un `array` y te devuelve `true` si lo encuentra o `false` si no lo hace.

```js
var frase = "Hello world, and to the universe.";

if (frase.includes(" and ")) {
  alert('Se encuentra');
}
else {
  alert('No se encuentra');
}
```

**Referencia:** [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/includes)

Comment: Esto no es una regex. La pregunta pedía una regex.

Answer (score 2):

Sugiero

```
\band\b
```

`\b` es un límite de palabra. Hace match si en esa posición hay algún tipo de separación de palabra (inicio o fin de cadena, o un separador como un espacio, por ejemplo).

Edito: ahora, si lo que quieres es literalmente que esté rodeada por espacios (espacio antes y después, y solo espacio), el regex sería (sin las comillas)

```
" and "
```

Es decir, literalmente el regex sería un espacio, la palabra *and*, otro espacio.